# Matlab: Removing duplicate interactions

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a Protein-Protein interaction data of homo sapiens. The size of the matrix is <4850628x3>. The first two columns are proteins and the third is its confident score. The problem is half the rows are duplicate pairs

if protein A interacts with B, C, D. it is mentioned as

- A B 0.8
- A C 0.5
- A D 0.6
- B A 0.8
- C A 0.5
- D A 0.6

If you observe the confident score of A interacting with B and B interacting with A is 0.8

If I have a matrix of <4850628x3> half the rows are duplicate pairs. If I choose Unique(1,:) I might loose some data.

But I want  <2425314x3> i.e without duplicate pairs. How can I do it efficiently?

Thanks
Naresh

Comment: If you sort by column 1, can't you just drop the second half of the rows? That's assuming there will always be pairs

Comment: @Dan I assume that somewhere down the line, protein C will interact with D. If you remove the bottom half of the rows, row `C D ...` will be removed along with `D C ...`. You need to enforce some ordering on the proteins and remove rows in which `col 1 > col2`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that in your matrix you store each protein with a unique id.
(Eg: A=1, B=2, C=3...) your example matrix will be:

```
M =

    1.0000    2.0000    0.8000
    1.0000    3.0000    0.5000
    1.0000    4.0000    0.6000
    2.0000    1.0000    0.8000
    3.0000    1.0000    0.5000
    4.0000    1.0000    0.6000
```

You must first `sort` the two first columns row-wise so you will always have the protein pairs in the same order:

```
M2 = sort(M(:,1:2),2)

M2 =

     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
```

Then use `unique` with the second parameter `rows` and keep the indexes of unique pairs:

```
[~, idx] = unique(M2, 'rows')

idx =

     1
     2
     3
```

Finally filter your initial matrix to keep unly the unique pairs.

```
R = M(idx,:)

R =

    1.0000    2.0000    0.8000
    1.0000    3.0000    0.5000
    1.0000    4.0000    0.6000
```

Et voilà!