# MATLAB array duplicates in different columns

Tags: matlab, duplicates

I have numeric array, but due to certain aspects of my program it makes duplicates of every single pair in different columns.

For example:

```
1 2
2 4
2 1
4 2
1 3
3 1
```

What would be easiest way to remove these pairs?

Result has to be:

```
1 2
2 4
1 3
```

Comment: This exact question was asked a couple of weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811327/matlab-removing-duplicate-interactions#comment57364813_34811327 but it had no answer

Comment: Have you tried something? You'll get much more help by providing a solution - as ugly as it can be - instead of just asking for one.

Answer (score 1):

What about only keeping a row if its column 2 value is larger than column 1?

```
M = [1 2
     1 3
     2 4
     2 1
     4 2
     3 1]

idx = M(:,2) > M(:,1);
M_unique = M(idx,:);
```

as suggested by [beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker) here: [Matlab: Removing duplicate interactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811327/matlab-removing-duplicate-interactions#comment57364813_34811327)

Comment: This will work perfectly, thank you :)

Comment: `unique` can also handle [unique rows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html?refresh=true#btb0_85).

Comment: @excaza if you sort each row first

Comment: Oops, missed that part. It's early :p